# python twisted threading

Tags: python, twisted

Hi can you please tell me how use different functions in different thread using thread pool 
in twisted...say

I have a list of ids `x=[1,2,3,4]` where 1,2,...etc are ids(I got from data base and each one contains python script in some where disk).

what I want to do is

scanning of x traverse on list and run every script in different thread until they completed

---

Thanx Calderone, your code helped me a lot.

I have few doubts like I can resize threadpool size by this way.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.suggestThreadPoolSize(30)
```

say all 30 available threads are busy & there is still some ids in list(dict or tuple)
1-In this situation all ids will be traversed? I mean as soon as thread is free next tool(id)
will be assigned to freed thread?
2-there is also some cases one tools must be executed before second tool & one tool output will be used by another tool,how will it be managed in twisted thread. 3

Answer (score 14):

Threads in Twisted are primarily used via `twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread`.  Alternatively, there's a new interface which is slightly more flexible, `twisted.internet.threads.deferToThreadPool`.  Either way, the answer is roughly the same, though.  Iterate over your data and use one of these functions to dispatch it to a thread.  You get back a `Deferred` from either which will tell you what the result is, when it is available.

```
from twisted.internet.threads import deferToThread
from twisted.internet.defer import gatherResults
from twisted.internet import reactor

def double(n):
    return n * 2

data = [1, 2, 3, 4]

results = []
for datum in data:
    results.append(deferToThread(double, datum))

d = gatherResults(results)
def displayResults(results):
    print 'Doubled data:', results
d.addCallback(displayResults)
d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
```

You can read more about threading in Twisted in the [threading howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html).